# ASP.NET MVC 4 Recursive Model Binding from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, fabricjs

I'm working with [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), saving drawing objects to a database. We use groups quite a bit, resulting in several levels of nested drawing objects. I've created classes that match the values being sent back from the canvas object, and it's correctly binding the top-level items in my drawing. It's not binding any of the sub-items, however, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

My model (some properties removed to keep it short:

```
public class DrawingObj
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; } //will be populated manually

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("originX")]
    public string OriginX { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("originY")]
    public string OriginY { get; set; }

    ....

    [JsonProperty("objects")]
    public ICollection<DrawingObj> ChildObj { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("points")]
    public ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public decimal X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Json. Sorry, there's a lot.

```
{"objects":[{"type":"group","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":461,"top":278,"width":126,"height":247.5,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","objects":[{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":126,"height":247.5,"fill":"white","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":-123.75},{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":123.75},{"type":"line","x":63,"y":123.75},{"type":"line","x":63,"y":-123.75},{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":-123.75}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":125,"height":246.25,"fill":"white","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":-123.125},{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":123.125},{"type":"line","x":62.5,"y":123.125},{"type":"line","x":62.5,"y":-123.125},{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":-123.125}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":111.38,"height":231,"fill":"white","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":-115.5},{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":115.5},{"type":"line","x":55.6875,"y":115.5},{"type":"line","x":55.6875,"y":-115.5},{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":-115.5}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":96,"height":215.25,"fill":"#C9C9C9","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":-107.625},{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":107.625},{"type":"line","x":48,"y":107.625},{"type":"line","x":48,"y":-107.625},{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":-107.625}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":91.5,"height":210.75,"fill":"black","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":-105.375},{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":105.375},{"type":"line","x":45.75,"y":105.375},{"type":"line","x":45.75,"y":-105.375},{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":-105.375}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":90,"height":209.62,"fill":"#A5EDF2","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":-104.811},{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":104.811},{"type":"line","x":45,"y":104.811},{"type":"line","x":45,"y":-104.811},{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":-104.811}]},{"type":"custom-circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":20,"height":20,"fill":"white","stroke":2,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","radius":10},{"type":"named-text","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":6,"height":15.6,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","text":"1","fontSize":12,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Times New Roman","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true,"name":"label"}]},{"type":"group","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":598,"top":277,"width":126,"height":247.5,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","objects":[{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":126,"height":247.5,"fill":"white","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":-123.75},{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":123.75},{"type":"line","x":63,"y":123.75},{"type":"line","x":63,"y":-123.75},{"type":"line","x":-63,"y":-123.75}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":125,"height":246.25,"fill":"white","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":-123.125},{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":123.125},{"type":"line","x":62.5,"y":123.125},{"type":"line","x":62.5,"y":-123.125},{"type":"line","x":-62.5,"y":-123.125}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":111.38,"height":231,"fill":"white","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":-115.5},{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":115.5},{"type":"line","x":55.6875,"y":115.5},{"type":"line","x":55.6875,"y":-115.5},{"type":"line","x":-55.6875,"y":-115.5}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":96,"height":215.25,"fill":"#C9C9C9","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":-107.625},{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":107.625},{"type":"line","x":48,"y":107.625},{"type":"line","x":48,"y":-107.625},{"type":"line","x":-48,"y":-107.625}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":91.5,"height":210.75,"fill":"black","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":-105.375},{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":105.375},{"type":"line","x":45.75,"y":105.375},{"type":"line","x":45.75,"y":-105.375},{"type":"line","x":-45.75,"y":-105.375}]},{"type":"rounded-polygon","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":90,"height":209.62,"fill":"#A5EDF2","stroke":1,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","points":[{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":-104.811},{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":104.811},{"type":"line","x":45,"y":104.811},{"type":"line","x":45,"y":-104.811},{"type":"line","x":-45,"y":-104.811}]},{"type":"custom-circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":20,"height":20,"fill":"white","stroke":2,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","radius":10},{"type":"named-text","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":6,"height":15.6,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","text":"2","fontSize":12,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Times New Roman","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true,"name":"label"}]}],"background":""}
```

Ajax call:

```
    var jsontext = JSON.stringify(canvas);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Project/SaveDrawing/',
        data: jsontext,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: onSaved,
        error: function (data, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveDrawing(ICollection<DrawingObj> objects)
    {
        try
        {
            if (objects != null)
            {
                bool saved = Drawing.SaveDrawing(objects);
                return Json(new { success = saved });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        return Json(new { success = false, error = error });
    }
```

So my two top-level items are binding exactly as expected, but ChildObj and Points are both null. I can't figure out why the collections aren't binding, because I believe I have the naming correct.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle the JSON binding/deserialization?

Comment: I added the controller and ajax call. When I inspect 'objects', it contains two DrawingObj items, and both ChildObj and Points are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default model binder doesn't adhere to the JSON.Net property attributes, hence the child JSON element `"objects"` is completely ignored.

Simply changing the child `"objects"` to `"childObj"` (to match the model property name) in the JSON will make this work with the default model binder.

```
{ "objects": 
    [{ "type": "group", "originX": "center", "originY": "center", ... 
        "childObj": [{ "type": "rounded-polygon", "originX": "center", "originY": "center", 
    ...
}
```

Otherwise do as The ZenCoder suggested and create a custom model binder that uses the JSON.Net property attributes.

Comment: Ok, this solution was simpler and also works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty much evident that the ASP.NET MVC `DefaultModelBinder` is not working correctly there.

One approach could be to create a **custom Model binder** for your object. First you would have to add one additional class to properly map the JSON you are posting to the controller.

```
[JsonObject]
public class ContainerObj
{
    [JsonProperty("objects")]
    public ICollection<DrawingObj> Objects { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("background")]
    public string Background { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would create a custom model binder to deserialize this object to what you need using JSON.NET:

```
public class ContainerObjModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ContainerObj))
        {
            var data = GetDocumentContents(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerObj>(data);
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    private string GetDocumentContents(System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request)
    {
        string documentContents;
        using (var receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                readStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return documentContents;
    }
}
```

And then you would register this custom model binder in `Global.asax`:

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ContainerObj), new ContainerObjModelBinder());
```

Finally, your controller would automatically recognize it needs to use the custom model binder:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDrawing(ContainerObj data)
{
    // Request processing
}
```