# JSON to Model property binding using JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm bound by agreements between my party and the client to use json parameters containing dashes. Since it's not possible to use that in property names in C#, I need to map to the desired property.

*What I do now:*

> The below code is simplified for convenience.

**Model**

```
public class MyRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("request-number")]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/load-stuff")]
public Stuff LoadStuff([FromUri]MyRequest request)
{
    return BackEnd.LoadStuff(request);
}
```

**Call to the API from client**

The above controller is targeted using this uri:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/load-stuff?request-number=X123&name=requestName
```

**My question**

If I put a breakpoint at the `BackEnd.LoadStuff` line I can see the call arrives, but the request isn't mapped correctly.

> Name contains what I expect: `requestName`,  but RequestNumber is `null`, so the mapping didn't work.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Hi have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925674/webapi-datamember-name-not-used-when-de-serializing-via-application-x-www-form-u

Comment: Also you can use ModelBinder instead, have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247992/querystring-model-binding-asp-net-webapi

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a related issue because my model-instance does arrive, it's just that (one of) the mappings failed. Everything's fine if I omit the '-'.

Comment: of course that it will arrive correctly if you ommit '-' because it will be the same name as you have on your model. Default ModelBinder is not case sensitive

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET's default model binder doesn't take the `JsonPropertyAttribute` into account when attempting to bind request parameters to a model (it can't, since it doesn't know about `JsonPropertyAttribute` and the rest of NewtonSoft.Json). Given your scenario  (property names that aren't legal identifiers in C#), the only way to achieve what you want is via a [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26493954/70345) that does read `JsonPropertyAttribute`.

If you did have property names that were legal identifiers (for example `request_number`) then you could create a request model with those named properties, then map it to a separate model with the correctly-named properties, e.g.:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/load-stuff")]
    public Stuff LoadStuff([FromUri]MyRequest request)
    {
        return BackEnd.LoadStuff(request.ToMyPrettyRequest());
    }
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public string request_number { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    MyPrettyRequest ToMyPrettyRequest()
    {
        return new MyPrettyRequest
        {
            RequestNumber = request_number,
            Name = name,
        };
    }
}

public class MyPrettyRequest
{
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```